# Debugging handling slightly different inputs

Tags: java, debugging

I am currently working on a Java compiler.  In the context of the compiler, slightly different inputs may result in different output (e.g. adding `final` in Java permits compiler to perform more optimizations).  In some other cases, different inputs may result into the same output (e.g. de-sugering some constructs - for-each loops).

When debugging how a compiler handles these cases, I usually run the compiler and try to figure out where the runtime execution path of the compiler diverge (or converge).  Needless to say, it's very tedious.

I am wondering if you have any tips that could help me debugging these situations.

Also, is there any tool that can trace two program executions and provide you the diffs of the execution path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on a CLI byte code -> native code JIT, which is different but we're facing similar obstacles. I put a special `ToString` method in that will pretty-print the current state of the byte code along with the strongly typed evaluation stack, etc. It allows me to visually inspect code transformations at each step with a text diff tool. Eventually I want to make a debugger visualizer that will "`ToString`" the code at each step and let me walk backwards/forwards directly in the debugger with highlighting for the changes.

If you pretty-print the syntax tree, you can diff it in a similar manner.

Edit: I wrote a basic `Annotator` class that interleaves the IL byte code with the assembly language representation of the generated native code. It has a `ToHtmlString()` method that allows me to take advantage of the HTML Visualizer built into the Visual Studio debugger. Please don't critique the ARM code - I just hacked something in so I could focus on the Annotator, and now that it's working I'll use it to work on proper codegen.

Right click → View image if you want to see it proper size. :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [280z28.org](http://www.280z28.org/images/vmx/2009-08-23-Annotator.png))</sub>