# Role of the garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection

While reading a course on the garbage collector I understood that it removes unreferenced objects from memory, I tried to answer some questions in a quiz related to the subject and I found this question:

The role of the garbage collector is to ensure that there is enough memory to run a Java program?

Is it true or false? I know it manages memory, but does it guarantee that there is enough memory to run a program?

Comment: false. it removes unreferenced objects from memory, you are right.

Comment: The amount of available memory doesn’t change. It’s the amount of *free* memory which the garbage collector tries to raise. Whether “to ensure” implies “guarantees” or allows to be interpreted as “tries at best effort”, I don’t know. Reads bad for a quiz question, being colloquial at a place where precise words are needed…

Answer (score 1):

It does, what it sounds exactly:

> "Garbage collection"

Garbage collector has not a responsibility of memory allocation or ensuring there is enough memory to run program.

So take a look at wikipedia about garbage collector : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)

Also according to oracle :

> What is Automatic Garbage Collection? Automatic garbage collection is
>   the process of looking at heap memory, identifying which objects are
>   in use and which are not, and deleting the unused objects. An in use
>   object, or a referenced object, means that some part of your program
>   still maintains a pointer to that object. An unused object, or
>   unreferenced object, is no longer referenced by any part of your
>   program. So the memory used by an unreferenced object can be
>   reclaimed.

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

And check that stacoverflow questiont also : [What's the difference between memory allocation and garbage collection, please?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183197/whats-the-difference-between-memory-allocation-and-garbage-collection-please)